# How to find xpath expressions for the elements in the html provided

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

How can I find xpath for

(1) old password

(2) new password

(3) confirm password

I want to find xpath expressions for the given elements. Here is the snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Comment: all are having id's . why don't you use it?

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working yet?

Comment: There is an XPath on the provided screenshot in the left bottom corner. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Though I would disagree that you want to use only xpath :

For **old Password** :

use  `id = "oldpass"`

For **new  Password** :

use  `id = "newpass"`

For **confirm Password** :

use  `id = "conpass"`

Answer (score 0):

Please find the XPath:

**Old Password :**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='oldpass']"));
```

**NewPassword :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='newpass']"));
```

**Confirm Password :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='conpass']"));
```

Unique ID is available for all the fields. So, you can find the element using ID instead of Xpath.

**Old Password :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("oldpass"));
```

**NewPassword :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("newpass"));
```

**Confirm Password :**

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("conpass"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, Right-click the HTML code of the element -> "Copy" -> "Copy Xpath"

you may also look at some Xpath Tutorials, https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

[image: Copy Xpath]